# DB2 Error while executing PL/SQL from Command Window

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor, db2

I am trying to run this PL/SQL example block given in the book Oracle to DB2 Conversion Guide. I am running this from the DB2 Command Window as db2 -vtd@ -f "check.sql". I have been trying since a couple of hours now. I keep getting the below listed error.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_employee(p_empno IN employee.empno%TYPE)
 IS
 r_emp employee%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN
    DELETE FROM employee WHERE empno = p_empno
    RETURNING * INTO r_emp;
    IF SQL%FOUND THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted Employee # : ' || r_emp.empno);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name : ' || r_emp.LASTNAME);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department : ' ||  r_emp.WORKDEPT);
    ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee # ' || p_empno || ' not found');
    END IF;
 END@
```

**DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "employee" was found following"_EMPLOYEE(p_empno IN".  Expected tokens may include:  "".  LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42601**

If I remove the IN Keyword, then I get errors for IS and rowtype. Is there anything I am missing here ?

Thank You.

Comment: It looks like the Oracle compatibility mode, which is required for PL/SQL dialect support, is not enabled in your database, so PL/SQL syntax is not recognized.

Comment: @mustaccio : Thank you. I think you are right. I am using the Express-C edition which apparently does not support PL/SQL. Only the Enterprise Edition of DB2 supports this.

Comment: Is there any workaround you can think of instead of using rowType?

Comment: All current editions of DB2 for LUW include Oracle compatibility features. The `%ROWTYPE` PL/SQL feature is also available in DB2 native SQL PL -- search the manual for _anchored type_.